# How can style the backdrop of a MaterialUI modal?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I have a MUI Modal set up, it's currently working, however the backdrop is being displayed as black. I have styling  in place, but for some reason the backdrop is not being updated and remains pitch black.

My code is below, a screenshot is also below of what I see when the Modal is opened. Please let me know how I can fix this issue.

[image]

```
import { Box, Modal, Typography } from "@material-ui/core";
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  modalStyle: {
    position: "absolute",
    top: "50%",
    left: "50%",
    transform: "translate(-50%, -50%)",
    width: 300,
    bgcolor: "background.paper",

    boxShadow: 24,
    p: 4,
    backgroundColor: "white",
    borderRadius: "10px",
  },
}));

const PopupModal = ({ postModalOpen, handleClose, children }) => {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <Modal open={postModalOpen} onClose={handleClose}>
      <Box className={classes.modalStyle}>
        ModalText
        <Typography
          id="modal-modal-title"
          variant="h6"
          component="h2"
          style={{
            fontSize: "14px",
            marginLeft: "5px",
          }}
        >
          {children}
        </Typography>
      </Box>
    </Modal>
  );
};

export default PopupModal;
```

Answer (score 3):

We can use `slots` and `slotProps` of modal props.

For example:

```
<Modal
  open={isOpened}
  onClose={() => setIsOpened(false)}
  closeAfterTransition
  slots={{ backdrop: Backdrop }}
  slotProps={{
    backdrop: {
      sx: {
        //Your style here....
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(69, 89, 167, 0.4)',
      },
    },
  }}
>
//Your content here...
</Modal>
```

I hope this can be helped.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I customized my MUI Backdrop (MUI v5)

```
<Backdrop open={isOpen} sx={{ backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25)', zIndex: 1 }} onClick={handleCloseMenu} />
```

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to style the backdrop, your styles must be passed to the `Modal` component directly:

For example:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  /** Changed modalStyle */
  modalStyle: { backgroundColor: "rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5)" },
  /** Moved content styling to new class */
  contentStyle: {
    /** Also removed some invalid attributes **/
    position: "absolute",
    top: "50%",
    left: "50%",
    transform: "translate(-50%, -50%)",
    width: "300px",
    backgroundColor: "white",
    borderRadius: "10px"
  }
}));

const PopupModal = ({ postModalOpen, handleClose, children }) => {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    // Note the changed className props with your sample code
    <Modal
      open={postModalOpen}
      onClose={handleClose}
      className={classes.modalStyle}
    >
      <Box className={classes.contentStyle}>
        <Typography
          id="modal-modal-title"
          variant="h6"
          component="h2"
          style={{
            fontSize: "14px",
            marginLeft: "5px"
          }}
        >
          {children}
        </Typography>
      </Box>
    </Modal>
  );
};
```

Working Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-edhqx?file=/demo.js

[image: Screenshot of working example]

FYI: You can also override all backdrops in your application, on a [global](https://v4.mui.com/customization/globals/) scale, by passing a [`MuiBackdrop`](https://v4.mui.com/customization/globals/) override object to `createMuiTheme()`.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense and your example works. However, when I try to apply color and opacity, the color goes back to being black, and even the colors I apply seem to be off slightly. I think there is something going on beyond styling, perhaps multiple Modals are being opened and being layered on one another, just not sure...

Comment: @Alex Do you have a codepen/codesandbox that reproduces the error that I can take a look at?

Comment: It's difficult to replicate, but was able to fix the issue. I did it by implementing the "Unstyled" Modal as outlined on the mui website. I was then able to add the customization I needed. Still not sure why the initial Modal didn't work... I'm guessing I had clashing style sheets.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simplest solution that worked for me. I used the `sx` property of the Modal component to set the style of the css class used by materialUI.

```
    <Modal
        open={props.open}
        onClose={props.onClose}
        aria-labelledby="modal-modal-title"
        aria-describedby="modal-modal-description"
        sx={{
            '& .MuiModal-backdrop': {
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 150, 150, 0.5);',
            },
        }}
    >
        <Card className='modal'>
            {props.children}
        </Card>
    </Modal>
```

While you can use a simple hex value to set the color (such as `backgroundColor: '#00ADB5'`, this will completely omit the transparency of the backdrop. If you want to keep the opacity, you should use the `rgba()` function as it allows you to set the opacity in the 4th argument (In the above example, it is 0.5)

I am not sue if this is the most elegant solution but this is the simplest one that worked for me. Hope this helps.