# Material UI Dialog with container Backdrop not overlay on elements with z-index

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am using material UI Dialog with container to show the dialog on top of specific element. When dialog is opened, the backdrop is behind the dialog, but some elements with z-index are shown above backdrop.

I know that we can change the z-index of those elements to 0 when dialog is opened. But do we have any proper solution ?

Anyone has solution for this ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71770094/5517161

i found an answer where you can pass in the z-index as parameter, at this point of time i can't reproduce it since i have to create a whole project but i'd like to help.

Comment: @MoDGenesis when I change z-index of backdrop, the elements behind with z-index are not showing any difference (ie., still it is on top of backdrop).

Comment: Maybe try to look into chrome -> f12 key which opens chrome debugger -> elements tab-> select in the html the backdrop html and at the right you'll see styles. try to manually set the z-index: 100000, or even add !important to it. e.g. z-index: 10000 !important;